# Regular expression to replace comma with dot within an SQL statement

Tags: regex

I'm in the process of migrating from Oracle to PostGreSQL. One issue that I found is that I need to replace "," with "." for numeric values.

E.g.

```
Insert into DAILY_DATA_READING (READING_ID,MG_ID,DAILY_READING_DATE,ACQUISITION_DATE,PUBLISHED,PUBLISHING_DATE,POD_ID,VB_DAILY,VM_DAILY,VB_TOT,VM_TOT,VM_TOT_AL,CONV_QMAX_FLOW_RATE,GATH_CONV_QMAX_FLOW_RATE_DATE,RECORD_VALIDITY,PARTITION_INDEX) 
values ('1028','99990000000010001',to_timestamp('16-OCT-12 06:00:00,000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS,FF'),to_timestamp('16-OCT-12 08:27:10,704000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS,FF'),null,null,'99990000000010','13','48','93','234','35',
'101,4000015258789',to_timestamp('15-OCT-12 12:20:00,000000000','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS,FF'),'S','10');
```

In this example I have to replace **101,4000015258789** with **101.4000015258789**.
I have tried with a simple text scanning which searches for "," followed by 8 digits and replacing it with "." but I ended replacing also timestamp columns. 
Is it possible to build a regular expression which replaces just the 14th field contained in the INSERT statement ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: What programming language are you using?  Regular expression replacement strings depend on the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL, replace

```
('[0-9]*),([0-9]+')
```

with

```
$1.$2
```

***or*** (depending on what program you are using)

```
\1.\2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to sed then you can do:

```
sed -r "s/('[0-9]+),([0-9]{8,}')/\1.\2/g" file.sql
```

OR on Mac:

```
sed -E "s/('[0-9]+),([0-9]{8,}')/\1.\2/g" file.sql
```